# How to use Junit5 without maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, junit5

If you see the junit official website it gives examples of Junit5 with maven/gradle. 
Is it possible to make a simple java project using Junit5 without using maven etc.?

Comment: If you seriously do Java, you cannot really avoid using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: @pensee what is the reason for not using a build tool? or you want to do it just for the learning purpose?

Comment: I have an assignment. It requires to use Junit5. But prof hasn't taught or mentioned anything about maven. I am not sure he expects me to figure maven out or do it without maven

Comment: I recommend https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to download the junit5 JARs as mentioned in https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview . How to run the tests? here: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests.

Theoratically, Maven, Gradle, Ant or any other build tools are the tools to make your dependency management easier and you can do it yourself as in the early days of Java if you want to. However, why you want to do that? Why not just use the great build tools to save your time?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, here one exemple on how to do it with steps:

```rb
#1 Download JUnit Console Laucher Jar
$Var=junit-platform-console-standalone-1.8.2.jar
$ curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-console-standalone/1.8.2/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.8.2.jar --output $Var

#2 Compile your test classes with the jar in the class path
$ javac -cp "junit-platform-console-standalone-1.8.2.jar" ClassName.java ClassNameTest.java

#3 Execute
$ java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.8.2.jar -cp "." --select-class ClassNameTest
```

If you're uncomfortable with curl just download the .jar manually.

The output of your tests should look like:

```rb
Thanks for using JUnit! Support its development at https://junit.org/sponsoring

╷
├─ JUnit Jupiter ✔
└─ JUnit Vintage ✔
   └─ SumTest ✔
      ├─ sumTest ✔
      └─ sumTest2 ✘ expected:<10> but was:<9>

Failures (1):
  JUnit Vintage:SumTest:sumTest2
    MethodSource [className = 'SumTest', methodName = 'sumTest2', methodParameterTypes = '']
    => java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<10> but was:<9>
       org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
       org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
       org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:647)
       org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:633)
       SumTest.sumTest2(SumTest.java:12)
       java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
       java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
       org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
       [...]

Test run finished after 135 ms
[         3 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         3 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         3 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         2 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         2 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         1 tests successful      ]
[         1 tests failed          ]
```

One use case to justify its use would be:

Automated execution of JUnit 5 test cases using Console Launcher and Jenkins.